# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2098a5c0'

Tags: ios, objective-c

my code is giving `[__NSMallocBlock__ size]` error on the last line. I trying to use this class to implement custom pinch to crop on image, but it seem to have some problem with the line "self.cropView.image =self.image;".

```
@interface PECropViewController () <UIActionSheetDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) PECropView *cropView;
@property (nonatomic) UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
@end
@implementation PECropViewController
+ (NSBundle *)bundle
{
    static NSBundle *bundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PEPhotoCropEditor" withExtension:@"bundle"];
        bundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithURL:bundleURL];
    });
    return bundle;
}

static inline NSString *PELocalizedString(NSString *key, NSString *comment)
{
    return [[PECropViewController bundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:@"Localizable"];
}

- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.view = contentView;
    self.cropView = [[PECropView alloc] initWithFrame:contentView.bounds];
    [contentView addSubview:self.cropView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                 target:self
                 action:@selector(cancel:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                 target:self
                 action:@selector(done:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                 target:nil
                 action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *constrainButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:PELocalizedString(@"Constrain", nil)
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                       target:self
                                                                       action:@selector(constrain:)];
    self.toolbarItems = @[flexibleSpace, constrainButton, flexibleSpace];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    self.cropView.image =self.image;
}
```

Comment: Please give us full crash report or full set of code. In code above we don't even know what cropView is.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski, can you please have a look now?

Comment: It looks fine. Where do you set image property to some value ? Are you sure it's not "nil" ?

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzKrukowski, you are right, when I try to pass an image directly to this class it doesn't accept it and throws this error, but if I set the image from an imageview like {PECropViewController *controller=[[PECropViewController alloc] init]; controller.delegate=self; controller.image=self.imageview.image;} then it works fine. can you please explain why it does not take image directly?

Comment: Is this full class code ? Maybe you have a custom setter somewhere later ?

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem with the allocated memory for the image. The image in self.image is not set or the memory for it is not properly allocated. You can allocate the memory for the image:

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

It helped me in a similar situation.